# How to create ContentDialog in UWP project

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am writing an Xamarin.Forms application, and in the UWP project, I want to write platform-specific code to prompt a dialog box. I am trying to write a custom `ContentDialog` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<controls:ContentDialog
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;assembly=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"
           x:Class="MyApp.Forms.UWP.Dialogs.SingleInputDialog"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           x:Name="ContentDialog"
           Title="TITLE"
           mc:Ignorable="d">

</controls:ContentDialog>
```

When I try to add a `Grid` or a `Textbox` in it, the intellisense doesn't show that any of these controls exist...I think I'm missing something trivial/obvious? I tried copying/pasting the example from the Microsoft documentation and I have the same problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create content control and call it in your code

```
 <ContentDialog
        x:Class="TestButton.MessageDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:TestButton"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TITLE"
        PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
        SecondaryButtonText="Button2"
        PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
        SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

        <Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentDialog>
```

Create a class and call above control (as shown below) and then you can refer to below function to show a dialogbox.

```
 public ContentDialogResult ShowMessage(string message, string primaryButtonText = "OK", string secondaryButtonText = "", bool isSecondaryButtonEnabled = false)
        {
            MessageDialog newDialog = new MessageDialog() { MaxHeight = 1000, MaxWidth = 1000 };
            newDialog.Title = "";
            newDialog.Content = message;
            newDialog.IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = isSecondaryButtonEnabled;
            newDialog.PrimaryButtonText = primaryButtonText;
            newDialog.SecondaryButtonText = secondaryButtonText;
            newDialog.HorizontalAlignment = left;
            return newDialog.ShowAsync().GetResults();
        }
```

Hope that helps